# What can you say about a continuous function that is zero at all integer values?

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, continuity, uniform-continuity

> Written with [StackEdit](https://stackedit.io/).
>
> Let $f: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R $ be a **continuous function** such that $f(i) = 0 \ for \ all \ i \in \Bbb Z$. Then which of the following is true : -
>
> A. Image(f) is closed in $\Bbb R$
>     B. Image(f) is open in $\Bbb R$
>     C. f is uniformly continuous
>     D. None of the above

For the correct option, look at the end of the question.

I tried to contradict the options by bringing examples(It was obviously the first step considering 'None of the above was' an option)

I wasn't able to think of a single function that contradicts either of the options. However, graphically I would say that these functions satisfy the hypothesis and contradict the options
(Image uploaded)
[image]
Here's what the functions are

1) Just like $sin x,$ the function touches 1 and -1. The major difference would be that this function touches the x-axis at all integral values and no where else.

2) The second graph touches the integers and zero and in each interval $(m,m+1)$, the graph's maximum and minimum value tend to increase slightly and they tend to +1 and -1 as $x \to \infty$ Thus, the function gets arbitrarily close to 1 and -1 without touching them.

3) The third graph is just like $x Sin(x)$. The difference is that this one touches the x-axis at integer values. With each interval $(m,m+1)$, our graph has its 'magnitude of difference' increasing.

Are my graphs correct? If they, can they explicitly be expressed as familiar functions? If not, which explicitly express-able  examples can be used to contradict the first three options?

The correct answer is D

Source - Tata Institute of Fundamental Research Graduate Studies Exam 2016

Comment: What do you mean by the image of $f$ is continuous? Do you mean it is closed?

Comment: Yes, thanks.

Edit : - Changed option A from 'Image(f) is continuos' to 'Image(f) is Closed)'

Comment: Take $f(x) = A(x)\cdot \sin (\pi x)$ with the amplitude $A(x)$ chosen according to each need.

Comment: "I wasn't able to think of a single function that contradicts either of the options." I don't believe you because it's impossible for such a function to satisfy A,B, and C all at the same time. Any example will be a counter-example for at least one of them.

Comment: @Daniel : - Thanks, it was perfect. Moreover, I feel glad that it is somewhat related to the graphs I created!       And Mercio -  I am sorry, I said a 'A aingle function contradicting either of the options', not a single functions contradicting all of the options... Out of curiousity, Would it really be impossible though? Are you saying so because we conclude something about uniform continuos image of $ /Bbb R$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By multiplying any polynomial $P(x)$ by $\sin^2(\pi x)$ (if you want to respect the sign of the polynomial, use $\sin(\pi x)$, if not), you can obtain those functions, which are (in radians):

[Clic here for seeing the graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5qci8.png)

The first is: $\sin(\pi x)$ (red)

The second one is **almost** : $\frac{x^2}{1+x^2}\sin(\pi x)$ (green) (I could not find a "nice" function here, thanks LutzL)

The third one is: $ax^2 \sin^2(\pi x)$ or $x \sin(\pi x)$ (blue)

[Here is an example](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/kaoxpf6xtj).

Comment: FYI, It is typically frowned upon to include external links. What if they go bad? Better to embed the image into the answer itself.

Comment: I am new here, I tried but it didn't let me do that.

Comment: The second is more like $P(x)=\frac{x^2}{1+x^2}$ in that it approaches but never reaches $1$. The range is thus $[0,1)$ or $(-1,1)$.

Answer (score 3):

Here's one example that violates A,B,C:

$$f(x)= \frac{x^2}{1+x^2}(\sin^2(\pi x))^{1/(1+x^2)}.$$

The fraction out in front prevents $f$ from ever reaching $1,$ so $f(\mathbb R) = [0,1),$ which is neither open nor closed in $\mathbb R.$ The exponent insures that this function is not uniformly continuous. This is because

$$(\sin^2(\pi (n+h)))^{1/(1+(n+h)^2)} \to 1$$

so there will be sequences $x_n,y_n \to \infty$ such that $|x_n-y_n| \to 0$ such that $|f(x_n)-f(y_n)| \ge 1/2.$